# Notifying apt module "apt_update" from custom puppet module

Tags: puppet, apt

I'm trying to configure APT to not install recommended packages. I'm using puppetforge puppetlabs/apt module so I wish to notify the `Exec['apt_update']` resource from that module.

I'm using this:

```
  class init {

    include apt

    # Configure apt to not install recommends
    file { "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80mymodule-norecommends":
        ensure => present,
        owner => root,
        group => root,
        mode => 644,  
        source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/apt/80mymodule-norecommends",
        notify => Exec['apt_update'],
    }

  }
```

However I get the following error:

> Could not find dependent Exec[apt_update] for
>   File[/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80mymodule-norecommends] at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/apt.pp:18

I have tried several syntax options (like `notify => Apt::Exec['apt_update'],`) but I don't get why I can't notify that resource.

Comment: Weird. You can try `notify => Class['apt::update']`, but your code *should* work.

Comment: Same: `Could not find dependent Class[Apt::Update]`. Seems that for some reason I cannot reach that scope, although "include apt" works.

Comment: Umm, you gave me a clue. My class is called "apt" too. The initial syntax seems to work if I replace `include apt`  with `include ::apt`...

Comment: Oh, you have some `apt` class shadowing the one from the module. Yes, that is most unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix said, I had some `apt` class shadowing the one from the module.

I replaced:

```
include apt
```

with:

```
include ::apt
```

And the issue was fixed.